# Batch File not kicking off another batch file

Tags: batch-file, marathontesting

I have created a batch(batA) file that kicks off another batch(marathon.bat) file. When I save batA onto my desktop and use

```
start /wait ..\marathon\marathon.bat -batch "C:\stuff"
```

it works just fine. However, when I save marathon.bat to my program files, which now has spaces in the name, and then use

```
start /wait c:\"Program Files (x86)\marathon\marathon.bat" -batch "c:\stuff"
```

I get the error:

```
'c:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I know that you have to use double quotes so that it takes the spaces into consideration, but why is it stopping at c:\Program? I've tried moving the quotes around to different locations, but I can't seem to get it to recognize the second file.

Comment: should `c:\"P.."` not be `"c:\P.."` ?

Comment: I've already tried that and it didn't work. I'll try it once more though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
 start "" /wait %comspec% /c "c:\Program Files (x86)\marathon\marathon.bat" -batch "c:\stuff"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems with how you call your batch file.

First, you have placed your quotes at the wrong place. Instead of

```
start /wait c:\"Program Files (x86)\marathon\marathon.bat"
```

You should enclose your whole command with quotes, not only from the `Program Files` folder name:

```
start /wait "c:\Program Files (x86)\marathon\marathon.bat"
```

The second problem is that the first parameter with quotes specified to the `START` command is treated as the title of the new window. You should add an empty set of quotes before your command to circumvent this:

```
start "" /wait "c:\Program Files (x86)\marathon\marathon.bat"
```

Comment: I put the double quotes there because earlier in the batch file that is the way that i have to kick off a vbscript. 'c:\"rest of file path"' works while '"c:\rest of file path"' does not work. Also, adding the two sets of double quotes after the start command doesn't make any difference for me. I still get the same error.

Comment: @NickL Have you tried the part with the empty quotes? Does this fix your problem?

Comment: When you say empty quotes I assume you mean just after the start command (start ""). Yes, I have tried that and it doesn't work. I didn't know if you meant "" or " " (first one with no space between and second one with a space). I have tried both and neither of them work.

Comment: Are said start instructions within a loop of some sort? Do you close every quotation mark before? What does the interpreter say when you mean it does not work? (attempting the empty double quote solution)

Comment: @MrPaulch No loop. It is a very simple file. It kicks off a vbscript, If errorlevel == 0 then goto starttests which is where I'm running into this problem. I receive the same error when attempting the empty double quote solution.

Comment: Can you verify that the error comes fromt executing the start command or does it already trigger at the section where you execute the VB Script?